# How can I create an Ant script for parallel deployment in tomcat?

Tags: ant, tomcat7, versioning, web-deployment

I discovered the [Parallel deployment feature in Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) and I would like to use it in my app. I already have an Ant script to build and deploy the app but I would like to know if there is a nice way to combine it with Parallel deployment. I am now able to generate the file but when I try to use it in the deploy:

`<deploy url="" username="" password="" path="" war="file:ROOT##${versionNum}"/>`

I don't get the expected result because Ant don't seems to interpret the '#' character correctly. How can I solve it? Is it a problem with XML or an Ant specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking out the `file:` prefix from war attribute allows it to find the file.  I'm guessing there is a way to escape the ## for a file: URI but it works without it.

Secondly, you need to specify the `version` attribute in the deploy tag. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands. Otherwise your war will appear in the webapps directory as `foo.war` instead of `foo##0000.war`.

`<deploy url="" username="" password="" path="" 
    war="foo##${versionNum}.war" version="${versionNum} />`

I found the ant BuildNumber task useful: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html

`<buildnumber />` sets `${build.number}` based on a number in a file that it also increments.

Comment: You are right, I have used the version attribute and it works nice. Also I don't need the '##' in the file name since it was intended to specify the version. Now I generate a file.war and deploy it with the version set and it works fine. I had to update my jars to make it work since the version attribute was not available.